# Python gives error when unused parameter is removed

Tags: python, parameters

I'm learning python and I’ve hit a snag.
This is my script:

```
from sys import argv
script,filename = argv
txt = open(filename)
print txt.read()
```

This works but when I remove the script parameter ,for example :

```
from sys import argv
filename = argv
txt = open(filename)
print txt.read()
```

It gives the error:

> File "ex3.py", line 4, in 
>       txt = open(filename) TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found

Answer (score 4):

When you do `script, filename = argv`, you're assigning `script` to the first element of `argv` and `filename` to the second. However, when you do `filename = argv`, you're assigning `filename` to *the whole thing*. This means you're passing a list to `open`, which Python doesn't like.

If you don't need to use `script`, you can replace it with a single underscore like this:

```
_, filename = argv
```

As @raymonad stated in a comment below, you could also directly assign `filename` to the second element like this:

```
filename = argv[1]
```

Comment: Or you can simply use `argv[1]`.

Comment: why would I assign it to a second element of argv,I need only one parameter.

Comment: @NihalSahu because like I said, `filename = argv` makes `filename` a list - Python can't read your mind and just give you one element.

Answer (score 4):

```
import sys
print type(sys.argv)  # <type 'list'>
```

Actually [`argv`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html?highlight=sys.argv#sys.argv) is a list, you are trying to pass a list to the `open`, which expects the first parameter to be valid string (file name). That is why it fails.

If you actually don't need the other values then you can extract only the first parameter, like this

```
from sys import argv
txt = open(argv[1])
print txt.read()
```

Another important suggestion, if you are going to deal with files, use [`with`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) statement like this

```
from sys import argv
with open(argv[1]) as txt:
    print txt.read()
```

so that you don't have to worry about explicitly closing the file